# How do you use a range-based for loop on the values of a std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm trying to use `std::map::operator[]` to iterate over the values of a `std::map` with a range-based for loop, but the following doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream> // cout, endl
#include <map>      // map
#include <set>      // set

using namespace std;

int main () {
    using namespace std;

    const map<int, set<int>> m {{2, {201, 202}}, {3, {301, 302}}};

    for (int v : m[2])
        cout << v << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Here's the compiler's error message:

```
Test.c++:18:19: error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const map<int, set<int> >'
    for (int v : m[2])
```

The followup question is, Given that there are two versions of at(), why aren't there two versions of []?

Comment: `m.at(2)`. `operator[]` isn't const.

Answer (score 5):

`map::operator[]` inserts a new element into the map if the key isn't found, hence it cannot be `const`, and cannot be called on a `const` `map`.

Use `m.at(2)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`operator[]` will do one of two things.  It will find the element at that location if it exists and return it.  If there is no element at that location, it will value-initialize it, and then return it.

As such, it is neither logically nor programmatically `const`.

While you may say "but there is an element 2", the `const`ness of an operation depends only on the *types* of the arguments, not the value of the arguments.  And `m[int]` isn't guaranteed to have a valid element there.

To fix this, you can replace `m[2]` with `m.find(2)->second`.  This does undefined behavior if `2` is missing from the map, but if `2` is present it will evaluate to the same thing as `m[2]`.  Alterantively, `m.at(2)` will again do the same thing if `2` is present as a key, and throw an exception if is not present.

As an aside, when working on such a problem, try breaking your code down into smaller pieces.  `m[2];` all by itself on a line will fail to compile.  In fact, the error message told you that it could not find an `operator[]` -- that might have given you a clue what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your map `m` is declared `const` meaning that you can only call `const` functions on it.

`std:map::operator[]` is not a such function, since it will modify the map if the specified key is not found.

What you need is `std::map::at`, which is `const` so you can call it on your `const` map.